# Is it illegal if someone posts a photo of me that was taken by their front doorbell without me knowing?

Tags: copyright, privacy, england-and-wales, photography

I was given an address from someone who owes me money. I went to the address and rung the door bell, a lady answered the door. I asked if Tom was there, she replied no and no Tom lives here.

I apologized to the lady and explained to her that I was given this address by someone that owes me money, and that he had obviously misled me.

I said sorry again and went on my way. About two hours later a friend of mine called me and said that someone had posted a photo of me on Facebook asking if anyone new me. My friend knew the person who posted the photo, so they phoned him and told him he new me and I was kosher so remove the photo, which he has now done.

So was it illegal for him to post that photo taken of me without me knowing about it?

Comment: In what state did this happen?

Comment: southampton england

Comment: Was the photo of you in a public place, or stood on the doorstep of this house? Or was it captured from a CCTV camera, etc?

Comment: The question ends (emphasis added): “without me **knowing** about it”. Knowledge is not the same as consent.

Answer (score 5):

If this was anywhere in the United States, it was perfectly legal to post the photo.

The First Amendment allows people to freely share information, including pictures. People commonly believe that they have the authority to control who takes a picture of them and under what circumstances, but that is generally false. Anyone with a camera is generally free to photograph anyone or anything they want out in public.

You've also used the copyright tag on your question. The person who took the picture owns the copyright. Since that's the owner, there's presumably no problem with her posting it. Instead, it would be illegal for *you* to post that photo without obtaining a license from the homeowner.

Comment: Technically, this wasn’t in public as the photo was taken on private property. However, as it was taken with the permission of the property owner, that’s still fine.

Comment: Not in California: https://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/california-right-publicity-law

Comment: Not what in California? Not legal or not illegal?

Comment: @bdb484 re: "If this was anywhere in the United States, it was perfectly legal to post the photo."  Not in California.  A person owns their likeness and image in California.  The link in my 1st comment has the details.

Comment: @grovkin Can you claridy how this violates California's law? Your link says "the Right of Publicity in California protects against unauthorized uses of a person’s name or likeness for commercial and certain other exploitative purposes". This use does not seem to fall under these categories.

Comment: @Matt Very correct. The right of publicity is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Matt I am not sure what you mean by "this", but my comment was on this answer and not on the question.  The answer stated some general principles.  It created the impression that these principles were without exceptions.  It doesn't matter that these principles happen to apply to this particular case or that these exceptions are not related to the case that is being considered.  What I was pointing out was that the perception, that these principles were without exceptions, was too optimistic because such exceptions did exist.

Comment: @Matt this is actually one of the differences between addressing a professional audience vs addressing a student audience.  Professionals know that exceptions to general principles exist and that it may be the case that they don't apply to the situation or that they are omitted for the purpose of being de-emphasized when they do apply.  A student audience will generally be left with an impression that a principle is universally applicable if it is stated in absolute terms.

Comment: @grovkin I wish I had repeatedly used the word "generally" rather than stating my answer in absolute terms.

Comment: @bdb484 fair enough.  Point taken.

Comment: @DaleM My understanding is that permission of the property owner does not matter. The worst that can happen (in the absence of such permission) is that the photographer is considered to be trespassing, but that doesn’t restrict any subsequent dealing in the photo.